# If..else statement not working as expected

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a network design app which performs a simulation of a packet traversing the network given particular conditions which looks like this:
[image]
When I click on the Config button, I have an if..else statement which verifies whether the network prefix(the number after the slash /48 /64 etc) are the same, and if they are the same, the packet travels along the line.

As you can see the first two prefixes are the same and therefore the packet has traveled along the line(showcased by the green line) and for the last computer, the prefix is 64 and it hasn't been able to reach there.

This if statement is supposed to check for that:

**CODES**

```
/* enter is the ip entered */
if (enter != null) {

    /*Verify if all prefixes are the same*/

    /* s is the array that contains the prefixes */
    if (s[0] == s[1]) {

        /*every code in the if statement is for the animations*/

        var start = $("#sldr");
        if (!start.hasClass('started')) {
            start.addClass('started');

            $('#sldr').css({
                "left": startx[0],
                "top": 160 + starty[0],
                "visibility": "visible"
            });


            $("#sldr").css({
                'display': 'block',
                'transition': 'none',
                'width': '50px'

            }).animate({
                        left: endx[0] - 15,
                        top: 160 + endy[0]

                    }, 2000,
                    function () {
                        //add if statements here
                        //for lines: give a specific color of line and specify which kind of cables it is
                        //retrieve the values and add conditions, same for the devices
                        //save the line coordinates in an array and use it for the animation
                        paths[0].attr("stroke", "green");
                        start.removeClass('started');
                        $('#sldr').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //remove this for ease in width
                        $('#img2').css('visibility', 'visible');
                    });

        }
    }
    else if (s[1] == s[2]) {

        var start2 = $("#img2");
        if (!start2.hasClass('started')) {
            start2.addClass('started');

            $('#img2').css({
                "left": startx[1],
                "top": 160 + starty[1]
            });


            $("#img2").delay(2000).css({
                'display': 'block',
                'transition': 'none',
                'width': '50px'

            }).animate({
                        left: endx[1] - 15,
                        top: 160 + endy[1]

                    }, 2000,
                    function () {
                        //add if statements here
                        //for lines: give a specific color of line and specify which kind of cables it is
                        //retrieve the values and add conditions, same for the devices
                        //save the line coordinates in an array and use it for the animation
                        paths[1].attr("stroke", "green");
                        start2.removeClass('started');
                        $('#img2').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //remove this for ease in width

                    });
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#errorPrefix').dialog({ //dialog box for error message that prefix is not the same
            height: 190,
            width: 330,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            resizable: false,
            dialogClass: 'no-close error-dialog'
        });
    }

}

else {
    $('#error').dialog({ //dialog for the error message that ip hasn't been set
        height: 190,
        width: 330,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        resizable: false,
        dialogClass: 'no-close error-dialog'
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

```
/* enter is the ip entered */
if (enter != null) {

    /*Verify if all prefixes are the same*/

    /* s is the array that contains the prefixes */
    if (s[0] == s[1]) {

        /*every code in the if statement is for the animations*/

    }

    else if (s[1] == s[2]) {

        //animations
    }
    else {
        //dialog box for error message that prefix is not the same

    }
}


else {
    //dialog for the error message that ip hasn't been set

}
```

The problem here is that the dialog box which displays the error message that the prefix is not same is not opening.

Any problem in my if..else statement?

Comment: Please fix your indentation, to make it a bit more clear what you're doing.

Comment: Are you getting any output in the Javascript console?

Comment: @Joost Nope nothing. The animation stops when it finds that the prefix is not the same for the last PC but the dialog box doesn't open.

Comment: If you strip out all the clearly-irrelevant-to-the-question code (and please do do that!)  this seems to boil down to `if (s[0]==s[1]) {...} else if (s[1] == s[2]) {...} else {...}` (And then a stray extra `else` after that, possibly?)  Is that really the intended logic?  (Since you haven't shown us the contents of the `s` array it's hard to tell what it's supposed to be doing)

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code in dev tools? And you really should use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: With that code we can't know if your if-else is fine. What are `s[]` array and what contains?

Comment: @codemonkey: There's no need for `===` if the types are the same.

Comment: @DanielBeck I was intending to do that but I thought maybe there's a problem elsewhere because as per the logic, it's supposed to work. I'll do just that and put it down below.

Comment: Have you made simple checks to see if any of the if/else code blocks are invoked? A console.log statement perhaps?

Comment: Well, I ask because that logic doesn't really sound like it matches your description of the problem.

Comment: aside from removing the irrelevant-to-the-question-code have you verified the contents of `s[]`. Or are you sure you extracted the subnet masks from the entered IP correctly?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the point of using === is to _enforce_ that the types really are the same. You assume the types are the same but cannot guarantee it - Depends on where the data is coming from. It's a simple case of best practice. Which is why jslint will always flag usage of ==.

Comment: @codemonkey: I know what it's for. The fact is that naively following rules is not how to code well. I've seen at least as many bugs from people naively using `===` as I have from people naively using `==`.

Comment: You all have good points here. s[] array contains all the prefixes entered. @krato Yes I did verify whether I'm getting all the contents correctly using the console.log(). I changed the else if statement to an if statement and now the dialog appears but not after the 1st animation completes.

Comment: Your conditionals are fine, must be something with your variables.

Comment: From your code, when s[0] is equal to s[1], the first if will be satisfied. Hence it would never go to the else statement. It shows the green line and comes out of the if else code block. So the else part " //dialog box for error message that prefix is not the same" will never get executed if either s[0] == s[1] or s[1] == s[2]

Comment: @kameswarib That makes complete sense thank you. What can be the solution to my problem?

Comment: Do you want to show the error message when none of the prefix are same ? If so, if((s[0] == s[1]) && (s[1] == s[2])) { ... } else { //Error message }. It would depend on what you want to do with the if's, etc

Comment: I need the animation to play for the first two PCs that have the same prefixes, then if the prefixes are not the same, it displays the dialog box. Any way to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic is broken: you're testing if the first 2 prefixes are the same, then if yes you'll never enter others `else ìf` and `else`.

You should do like this:

```
if (enter != null) {

    /*Verify if all prefixes are the same*/
    if (s[0] == s[1] && s[1] == s[2]) {

        // 1st animation
        // 2nd animation
    }
    else {
        //dialog box for error message that prefix is not the same
    }
}
else {
    //dialog for the error message that ip hasn't been set
}
```

---

According to the OP comment about the answer above, here is the way to not only display error when not all prefixes are same, but nevertheless display animation for the ones which are same:

```
if (enter != null) {

    if (s[0] == s[1]) {
        // 1st animation
        if (s[1] == s[2] {
            // 2nd animation
        }
    }
    // Add error if not all prefixes are the same
    if (s[0] != s[1] || s[1] != s[2]) {
        //dialog box for error message that prefix is not the same
    }
}
else {
    //dialog for the error message that ip hasn't been set
}
```

NOTE that 2nd animation keeps contidioned to successfull 1st one.

Comment: Thanks I tried it and the dialog box appears if one of the prefixes is not the same but I would like that the animation plays for the first two PCs that have the same prefixes. Any way to do that?

Comment: The dialog box opens the moment it finds that a prefix is not the same and the animation plays at the same time. :/

Comment: @Damini Oh yes, didn't pay attention to it :) So simple... Edited.

Comment: Sorry but i'm getting the same output.

Comment: @Damini Huh... do you mean you want the error box to display only after the 1st animation ended? In this case, you already have the same problem when prefixes are all same: anim 1 et 2 work simultaneously, while you probably would like they reflect the progression (1, _then_ 2). For this, in the two situations, it's a totally different problem than the if/else issue of your OP! You'd use jQuery animations instead of CSS ones, so you can use the `complete()` option to launch next step. If you need help for that, create another question for it since, again, it's a totally different issue.

Comment: Thanks I've changed the way error messages are getting displayed now. I'm using a div to display notifications so no need to make the dialog box open after the animation has completed and so on. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Damini Glad you found a simpler solution. Thanks for keeping me informed.